# What test can I run?

Tags: spss

I am working on a research question where I am hoping to find a significant difference at multiple frequencies.

I am comparing two age matched groups (n= 217). I am trying to find the correct test to see if there is a significant difference in their mean thresholds at 10 different adjacent frequencies. There is data for each subject at each frequency. I originally wanted to use a paired t-test; however my advisor tells me it is a repeated measures violations. Does anyone have any ideas? Currently we are using a LOESS, but I would love to be able to use a more robust test.

Comment: Can you (a) spell out LOESS (b) say why you do not want to do some form of repeated measures analysis?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have two groups of independent, yet age-matched subjects.  Each subject has 10 data points - one for each of 10 frequencies.  Assuming this is correct:

You have a split-plot design that includes both a within-subjects and between-subjects condition.  While it sounds like a paired t-test might be the answer to compare across your groups, this is likely not appropriate, because although you've done your best to age-match subjects, you are not holding all subject-level variability constant. I suppose you could *do* the test if each subject in group A had a specific matched pair in group B, but I think you'd be better off treating them as separate groups, and maybe adding age as a covariate. Secondly, since each subject yields a score at each of 10 frequencies, that is a repeated measures factor, and should be treated as such.  It would be better to conduct an omnibus test first rather than compute all possible paired t-tests between the 10 frequencies.